# How to remove a specific duplicate string from a field in a text file?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file with three columns, and I need to remove lines that contain specific duplicated field.

```
 1 V(Cl8)                         2.121
 2 V(C1,H3)                       2.067
 3 V(Cl7)                         2.121
 4 V(Cl7)                         1.347
 5 V(C4,H6)                       2.067
 6 V(Cl8)                         1.347
 7 V(Cl8)                         0.918
 8 V(C1,Cl7)                      1.220
 9 V(C4,Cl8)                      1.220
10 V(Cl7)                         0.918
11 V(C1,C4)                       1.958
12 C(Cl8)                         7.668
13 C(Cl7)                         7.668
14 C(C1)                          2.087
15 C(C4)                          2.087
16 C(Cl8)                         2.267
17 C(Cl7)                         2.267
18 V(C1,H2)                       2.067
19 V(Cl8)                         2.122
20 V(Cl7)                         2.122
21 V(C4,H5)                       2.067
```

I need to remove the lines that contain repeated C(Cl8) and C(Cl7), so that I only have one occurrence of each in the output.

I tried commands like `sort` and `uniq`, but all the duplicated strings are removed.

The desired output (note that I don't care which occurrence is kept, I only care that I have just one `C(Cl8)` and one `C(Cl7)`:

```
 1 V(Cl8)                         2.121
 2 V(C1,H3)                       2.067
 3 V(Cl7)                         2.121
 4 V(Cl7)                         1.347
 5 V(C4,H6)                       2.067
 6 V(Cl8)                         1.347
 7 V(Cl8)                         0.918
 8 V(C1,Cl7)                      1.220
 9 V(C4,Cl8)                      1.220
10 V(Cl7)                         0.918
11 V(C1,C4)                       1.958
13 C(Cl7)                         7.668
14 C(C1)                          2.087
15 C(C4)                          2.087
16 C(Cl8)                         2.267
18 V(C1,H2)                       2.067
19 V(Cl8)                         2.122
20 V(Cl7)                         2.122
21 V(C4,H5)                       2.067
```

Comment: it's not a number, it's atomic symbol of Chlorine  (Cl)

Comment: Let's see if I understand. So lines 12 and 13 (Cl18, Cl17) have repeated values in the 3rd column. In the output you remove Cl18. Yo want to keep Cl17 or it doesn't matter which one is removed?

Comment: Dear schrodigerscatcuriosity,  what i'm looking for is search in the second column and find the duplicate C(Cl7) and C(Cl8) and remove the line.

Comment: @anasforum How do you decide which lines to keep/remove for values that appear more than once? In your example you keep line 16 and remove line 12 for C(Cl8), but keep line 13 and remove line 17 for C(Cl7).

Comment: The third column doesn't matter me if duplicated or not. the most important thing is to keep only one C(Cl7) and one C(Cl8) in the second column.

Comment: See @DonHolgo comment above. We need to know how do you decide which of the duplicates to remove. Why keep line 16 and not 12? Why keep line 13 but not 17?

Comment: it doesn't matter, it's just a random choice, the most important thing is to keep one C(Cl7) and one C(Cl8).

Comment: Is the use of `awk` a requirement of your problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about which of the duplicates is removed and are OK with keeping the first occurrence and removing the rest, you can use:

```
$ awk '/C\(Cl8\)/ && ++a > 1{next} /C\(Cl7\)/ && ++b > 1{next}1' file | color -l 'C\(Cl7\)','C\(Cl8\)'
 1 V(Cl8)                         2.121
 2 V(C1,H3)                       2.067
 3 V(Cl7)                         2.121
 4 V(Cl7)                         1.347
 5 V(C4,H6)                       2.067
 6 V(Cl8)                         1.347
 7 V(Cl8)                         0.918
 8 V(C1,Cl7)                      1.220
 9 V(C4,Cl8)                      1.220
10 V(Cl7)                         0.918
11 V(C1,C4)                       1.958
12 C(Cl8)                         7.668
13 C(Cl7)                         7.668
14 C(C1)                          2.087
15 C(C4)                          2.087
18 V(C1,H2)                       2.067
19 V(Cl8)                         2.122
20 V(Cl7)                         2.122
21 V(C4,H5)                       2.067
```

Comment: where is CCl8) and C(Cl7), they all disappeared ?  i'm looking to keep one match

Comment: @anasforum eek! Sorry, copy/paste error, see updated answer.

Comment: thank you very much, perfect result.

Comment: @terdon about your editing (not that I'm complaining), I didn't need to add the numerical sorting to have the result shown.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity maybe you have your locale set up differently (but that would be odd in this case) but without the `-n`, the data were sorted alphabetically so `10` was first and `9` was last and `1` was on line 9 etc.

Comment: Is it possible to search the duplicate of C(Cl8) and C(Cl7) using a regular expression ?

Comment: @anasforum that's a whole different question. The regex `C\(Cl[78]\)` will match both, but the details of how to use it will depend on what you are doing.

Comment: @terdon what i'm looking for is to detect duplicate of the kind C(Clx) no matter the number x, because i have a dozen files conatin the same data with different number x, so i trying to write a script for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option:

```bsh
$ sort -k2,2 file | sed -e 'N;s/^\(.*C(Cl7).*\)\n.*C(Cl7).*/\1/' -e 's/^\(.*C(Cl8).*\)\n.*C(Cl8).*/\1/' | sort -nk1,1
 1 V(Cl8)                         2.121
 2 V(C1,H3)                       2.067
 3 V(Cl7)                         2.121
 4 V(Cl7)                         1.347
 5 V(C4,H6)                       2.067
 6 V(Cl8)                         1.347
 7 V(Cl8)                         0.918
 8 V(C1,Cl7)                      1.220
 9 V(C4,Cl8)                      1.220
10 V(Cl7)                         0.918
11 V(C1,C4)                       1.958
12 C(Cl8)                         7.668
13 C(Cl7)                         7.668
14 C(C1)                          2.087
15 C(C4)                          2.087
# 16 C(Cl8)                         2.267 removed
# 17 C(Cl7)                         2.267 removed
18 V(C1,H2)                       2.067
19 V(Cl8)                         2.122
20 V(Cl7)                         2.122
21 V(C4,H5)                       2.067
```

Comment: Thank You All Very Much.